# How to query and save link in array to call later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia

I am doing a query in wikipedia to get a snippet and the title with the link. Then if i click a title I would like to get the full article in a modal.

I am trying to get different articles for each different link I get in the first query.

[Here it is a JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgyc8to4/12/)

```
$("#wiki").on('click', function(e) {
    var articleName = $(this).data('subject');
    $.getJSON("https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?", {
        srsearch: articleName,
        action: "query",
        list: "search",
        format: "json"
    }, function(data) {
        $("#results ul").empty();
        $("#results ul").append("<h3>Results for <b>" + articleName + "</b></h3>").text();
        $.each(data.query.search, function(i, item) {
            $("#results").append("<li><a href='http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title) + "' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.bs-example-modal-lg'>" + item.title + "</a><br>" + item.snippet + "</li");
            var myLink = $("#results ul li a").attr("href");
            $("#results div a").attr("href", "#");
        $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $.getJSON("https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&callback=?", {
                page: articleName, 
                prop:"text"
            }, function(data) {
                $(".modal-content").html(data.parse.text['*']);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<button id="wiki" data-subject="Paris">Wikipedia</button>
<output id="results">
 <ul>
 </ul>
</output>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.one()` at `#wiki` element `click`, `event.preventDefault()`, `event.stopPropagation()` at `ul a` element `click` event; set `page` to `e.relatedTarget.textContent` at `$.getJSON()` call within `show.bs.modal` event handler

```
$("ul").on("click", "a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
})
$("#wiki").one('click', function(e) {
    var articleName = $(this).data('subject');
    $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?", {
        srsearch: articleName,
        action: "query",
        list: "search",
        format: "json"
    }, function(data) {
        $("#results ul").empty();
        $("#results ul").append("<h3>Results for <b>" + articleName + "</b></h3>").text();

        //For each result i set a <li> with the title and snippet. 
        //The title will be a disabled link with the 
        //data-attributes to load the modal

        $.each(data.query.search, function(i, item) {
            $("#results").append("<li><a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title) + "' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.bs-example-modal-lg'>" + item.title + "</a><br>" + item.snippet + "</li");

        // At this point I set the url in a variable
        // Probably I should save the url in an array since I may have many results

            var myLink = $("#results ul li a").attr("href");

        // Here I disable the link

            $("#results div a").attr("href", "#");
        });

       // Here I say that as soon as the modal is open, 
       //I should make another query based on the title and get the full article
      // This is where I have the issue as the URL should be what I have saved

        $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&callback=?", {
                page: e.relatedTarget.textContent, 
                prop:"text"
            }, function(data) {
                $(".modal-content").html(data.parse.text['*']);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kgyc8to4/26/

Comment: If i click the button then I click on a title on the list, I always have the first link and load the same content while it should load different link and different content based on the results you get on the first query

Comment: @rob.m `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%20(disambiguation). No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.` What should value of `page` at second `$.getJSON()` be?

Comment: changed the http to https but i get 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_(disambiguation)' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Change `page` value to `e.relatedTarget.textContent`, include `e.stopPropagation()` at `$("ul").on("click", "a", function(){})`, see updated post.

Comment: one question, why do I need the ul a click?

Comment: Expected result is returned without that portion of `javascript`. Prevents `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%20(disambiguation). No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.` message at `console`.